# gb4e package causing capacity errors

Tags: errors, linguistics, gb4e

I was using this:

http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/examples/gb4e/

To try and create numbered examples in my document.

However, when I load it and put the example `exe` in that link in one of the separate Tex files (`Introduction.tex`) I include in `main.tex`, I get:

```
./Chapters/Introduction.tex:14:
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack s
ize=10000].
\gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
                       \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
l.14 ... and political news \cite{washington_post}
                                                  .  More importantly, when ...
```

Which is not even referring to the `exe` example I inserted but a couple of blocks of tex above it.

For info, here is my full code before my document begins:

```
\documentclass{report}
% [fontsize=11pt,border=5pt]
% standalone for the tree
\usepackage{forest}
% This overrides warnings like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% This is for hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\urlstyle{same}
% Not sure why I need to use this
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \graphicspath{ {images/} }
% \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}
% This is for numbered examples
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

Would appreciate some help as I feel like my Latex is very messy here.

Comment: Although I was able to answer your question with the error you provided, if you ask questions in the future, you should try to reduce your problem to a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (or in this case, a minimal non-working example that produces the error).

Comment: Related questions with the same error: [Parameter Stack Size Error with graphicx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127059)  and [Errors (1) missing \endcsname, (2) TeX capacity exceeded when including audio with media9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304586).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `gb4e` package redefines the underscore character so that it can be used in regular text mode. Although this is very useful for linguists, it can easily cause problems and in your case the problem is with your citation key `washington_post`.

The best way to solve this problem is immediately after loading `gb4e` you issue  the command

```
\noautomath
```

which turns off the redefinition.

Comment: You've saved my thesis defense presentation. Thank you. I was getting this with gb4e + beamer + abntex2 bibliographic packages.

Comment: This also seems to resolve a similar issue happening when using the `ling-macro` package, which is somewhat related with and dependent on `gb4e`.

Comment: OMG where were you 3 hours ago!